# Is it possible to parse dynamic xml-structured log contents with Grok?

Tags: parsing, dynamic, logstash, grok

Is it feasible using Grok to parse dynamic xml-structured log contents, such as:

```
<tag_1> contents </tag_1> ... <tag_N> contents </tag_N>
```

where "tag_*" would be the field name and "contents" - the actual contents.
Therefore the parsed message would look like:

```
{
  "tag_1": [
    [
      "contents"
    ]
  ],

....

  "tag_N": [
    [
      "contents"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with `grok`.  You will need to resort to ruby code to parse the XML and toss it into the `event` structure.

If your XML is super regular (ie has a root element and only one level under it), you could maybe use code like this:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
        msg = event['message'].split('><');
        for part in msg
            endpos = part.index('</')
            startpos = part.index('>')
            if !endpos.nil? && !startpos.nil? then
                tag = part[0,startpos];
                text = part[startpos+1,endpos-startpos-1];
                event[tag]=text
            end
        end
        "
    }
}
```

If your xml is more complex, you are going to have to resort to a real XML parser and figure out how to use it with logstash (I've never brought an external library into logstash).